# Change localhost:4200 to something mysite:4200 in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to change host name for testing purpose. I have tried 
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 
but app again runs on localhost:4200. Is there a way that app runs on different host name (word) in browser?

Comment: I mean, wrote something else here, I wrote the actual port actual port. But I want to word to be shown.

Comment: It has to be `localhost` though as the launch point, it is running on your PC and that address will always point back to your PC. That is not configurable, only the port number is.

Comment: @lgor - `0.0.0.0` is legal for the `--host` parameter for `ng serve`. It's simply telling `ng` how to bind. Using `0.0.0.0` is basically telling `ng` that it can accept requests from any IP address. The default binding is `127.0.0.1` and thus only requests from the local machine will work - but it actually doesn't matter the hostname (`localhost` or a custom one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on Mac or Linux and just for local testing, you can edit `/etc/hosts` and add your own dns mapping. I'm sure you can do something similar on Windows.

For example you can add adding `mysite` to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite
```

Then you can access your app by going to `http://mysite:4200`.

Note that if making changes to your hosts file don't appear to work you may need to either reboot or make your OS reload your hosts file. See the bottom of this page for more information: https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want

Comment: I've never heard of "reload the host file before".  I believe this to be wholly unnecessary.

Comment: You may very well be right. I just tried it myself and it didn't seem to cache the hosts file even if changing an existing value. I'll update the post to say if it doesn't work right away you _might_ need to flush your dns.

Comment: for windows the `hosts` file is located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the next row to the end of your hosts file: 127.0.0.1 my.local.host
2. Start app: ng serve --host "my.local.host"